# Rebuild/Re-organize index and Update statistics in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, index-tuning, index-statistics

For many of the sql servers we have seen that the SQL agent Maintenance job first runs the re-indexing and later as a second step it update stats with full scan.

I want to figure out if auto update stats seems to be working, is it mandatory to update stats straight away once re-index step completes?

Also, are there any scenarios where update stats can be done first and indexing step as second?

The reason for this being that we are witnessing slowness for app/ server which is getting fixed when we manually update the stats. So i am puzzled, if update stats is running fine, why we are facing this issue.

This maint'ce job runs twice a week. so is there a way we can pro actively figure the out of update stats even after successful job run

Comment: If you rebuild the index the stats are updated anyway, so doing it again is just wasteful. Same with updating the stats first and then rebuilding. For a reorganize they are not, but just because a reorganize happened does not necessarily mean that a stats update is necessary. Are you seeing problems related to statistics? Or is this just educational?

Comment: Rebuilding index with full scan updates stats for that index. So if you do stats update again its wastage. Please see Paul's article http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-10-rebuilding-indexes-and-updating-statistics/

Comment: @AaronBertrand :i believe problem on one of my server is with stats, as users reporting slow performance at application end. Last time when we fixed this was updating stats manually, so was wandering how can i prevent this from occurring again and again

Comment: How have you actually narrowed down that statistics are involved in this specific problem? Which statistics are you going to target for fixing? All of them? Cars smash into lamp posts all the time, but it's not always because the driver is drunk - sometimes they're texting, sometimes they're swerving to avoid a deer, sometimes they slipped on ice or a banana peel... be careful not to knee-jerk and come to conclusions. Investigate the actual execution plans for these slow queries, look at wait statistics, check these queries while they're running... for all you know, they're being blocked.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thanks will check for wait stats, but haven't noticed any sort of blocking for sure!

Comment: sys.dm_exec_requests and sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks will tell you exactly what those long-running queries are waiting on. The execution plan they're using should yield some clues too. A query being slow could be for all kinds of reasons that has nothing to do with indexes or statistics, especially if indexes and data haven't changed a lot (or at all).